# AFNetworking calling curl command to get access token

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking, access-token

I a curl command to get the access token, which looks below command -

curl --data 'client_id=XXX&grant_type=XXX&client_secret=XXX&scope=XXX' "https://abc-internal.XXX.com/as/resourceOwner" -k -i

I need to call this command from my objective C code to get the access token, here is my code which is not working -

```
 NSURL *strURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://abc-internal.XXX.com/as/resourceOwner"];
    NSString *icpStr = [strURL absoluteString];
    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];
    manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
    [manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"XXX" forHTTPHeaderField:@"client_id"];
    [manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"XXX" forHTTPHeaderField:@"grant_type"];
    [manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"XXX" forHTTPHeaderField:@"client_secret"];
    [manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"XXX" forHTTPHeaderField:@"scope"];

    AFSecurityPolicy *securityPolicy = [AFSecurityPolicy policyWithPinningMode:AFSSLPinningModeNone];
    [securityPolicy setValidatesDomainName:NO];
    [securityPolicy setAllowInvalidCertificates:YES];
    manager.securityPolicy = securityPolicy;

    [manager GET:icpStr parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        if ([responseObject isKindOfClass:[NSData class]])
        {
            NSError         *parseError = nil;
            NSDictionary    *resultsDictionary = (NSDictionary *) [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: responseObject options: 0 error: &parseError];
            if (parseError)
            {
                NSLog(@"Parse Error %@",parseError);
            }else{
                NSLog(@"Results %@",resultsDictionary);
            }
        }
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error %@",error.localizedDescription);
    }];
```

And i get error saying its bad request -

```
Error Domain=com.alamofire.error.serialization.response Code=-1011 "Request failed: bad request (400)"
```

Any suggestion would be much appreciated. I am new to objective c coding so i would really appreciate if someone can help me here.

Comment: `--data` that's not a header parameter, no? It's `-H` or `--header` for that. `--data` put the parameters into the HTTPBody (also, it seems to do `application/x-www-form-urlencode`, but your server might accept more "JSON like"). So it should be `parameters:@{@"client_id="xxx", etc.}` instead. Also, since you set the `responseSerializer` to `AFJSONRequestSerializer`, I don't think you need to set the `application/json`, I think it's already done.

Comment: @Larme  i tried that but now i get 401 error "Error Domain=com.alamofire.error.serialization.response Code=-1011 "Request failed: unauthorized (401)" How can we fix this?

Comment: No its working now!! I had set one parameter wrong. Thanks @Larme

Answer (score 0):

```
 NSString *URLString = @"https://abc-internal.XXX.com/as/resourceOwner";
AFHTTPSessionManager * manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
manager.responseSerializer =[AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];
[manager GET:URLString parameters:nil progress:^(NSProgress * _Nonnull downloadProgress) {
 } success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nonnull task, id  _Nullable responseObject) {
    if ([responseObject isKindOfClass:[NSData class]]) {
        NSError         *parseError = nil;
        NSDictionary    *resultsDictionary = (NSDictionary *) [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: responseObject options: 0 error: &parseError];
        if (parseError)
        {
            NSLog(@"Parse Error %@",parseError);
        }else{
            NSLog(@"Results %@",resultsDictionary);
        }
    }
} failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nullable task, NSError * _Nonnull error) {

}];
```